# Google map does not display properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Google Map widget on `Twitter Bootstrap's` Modal window.

When I open modal window, this map is displayed only on a part of a widget ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXAi3.png)).

After I re-size browser window this map is displayed properly.

I tried to user `$('#map').resize()` (on div with map) but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion on my issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had solved this problem before. Google Map will not display properly when you load the map into a "display:none" canvas. Bootstrap modal win will be hidden in the beginning. So you have to make sure that map canvas can't be hidden before Google Map finished loading.

My work around is move the canvas to a positon which user can't see it and load map into it. After a few second (maybe 500ms), move map to the right position (in your case is modal body).

I write a simple example. You could try it:

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="height:300px;margin-top:-1000px"></div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.modal-body').append($("#map").css("margin-top","0px").get(0));
        },500);
    });
```

Demo screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your answer. I think I found another decision. I initialize map this way(after displaying the modal):

`$('#new-order-window').modal ('show');` /
`if (!map)` /
`initialize();`