# Map displaying properly only on window change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, openlayers

I am working on a project that makes use of a map engine from some private company that I can't mention here.

The system used to be in JQuery, and we recently made some considerable modifications, and the system is now implemented in AngularJS.

On the left side of the screen, we have a slidebar displaying items.
On the right side of the screen, we have the map.

My issue is that when I load the page, the map does not display properly, and the inside overlay is quite small. I have checked their sizes but they are correct.

However, when I resize the window manually, or open the Element Inspector from G. Chrome, the map then gets displayed completely.

I have attempted to redraw the clusterLayer, resize the map, resize the div of the map, but nothing seems to be working.

I found this post [Google map does not display properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599180/google-map-does-not-display-properly), it could have solved my problem, but I don't have any power on how the map gets loaded.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any possibility you could put some code in jsfiddle that replicates the problem or does your reference to "private company that I can't mention preclude this"?

Comment: "private company that I can't mention" precludes this...

Comment: My idea on this is that AngularJS has not finished loading all contents and templates, which is why the problem occurs, as #map is set to width and height of 100% in CSS. If I change this to 1000px for example, the map will be displayed 1000x1000px, which, I guess, confirms my theory.
I tried in Angular to watch for the content to be loaded before applying 100% for width and height, but it does not work. So at the moment, I am setting 1000x550px until I find a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with ol3 in conjunction with angular. My workaround was to add:

$(document).ready(function () {map.updateSize()});

With map being my ol3 map object. In this case I did not use the openlayers directive from angular. Which, by the way, when used did not have the displaying problems.
Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had somewhat a similar problem and none of the solutions provided worked for me. So I used timeOut function like this and it worked:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
        map.updateSize();
   })
});
```